# Article about doing a PhD by prominent mathematician or computer scientist

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I vaguely remember reading an article(as an online pdf - possibly via twitter) on why one should/should not do a PhD; what doing a PhD entails. It was well structured and specifically mentioned that a PhD isn't for everyone. I also remember it was written by a prominent computer scientist(or a mathematician). Can anyone provide suggestions/hints about what article it might've been?

Comment: Surprisingly, nobody has voted to close because it's a shopping question.

Comment: This question is rather non-specific, rather along the lines of "I once heard a song. It goes something like this: Do do do do DO DO DO. Does anyone know the title?"

Comment: @Allure Flag "Question appears off-topic (data seeking)" was declined by mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some sources I have found that speak to the topic of not getting a PhD.

Perhaps this document is the one you are looking for? Both the authors are mathematicians with PhDs. I would not say they are necessarily prominent, but they are established.

http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/media/eps/schoolofmathematics/study/guide_2011.pdf

---

This is a short article reposted by a professor at Stanford University.

https://tomprof.stanford.edu/posting/545

---

Here are three other online articles about the topic.

https://medium.economist.com/why-doing-a-phd-is-often-a-waste-of-time-349206f9addb

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/aug/15/should-do-phd-you-asked-autocomplete-questions

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/12-reasons-not-to-get-a-phd/

---

I will add my own brief commentary here. Obtaining a PhD has never hurt me financially. I have a well paying full-time job that requires a PhD. (Now *should* the job require a PhD is a different story). There are many, many, many jobs in my field (statistics) that prefer a PhD. I have never regretted obtaining a PhD.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, people who earn doctorates do it because they love knowledge more than money.

Comment: @Buffy Which is amusing, since usually the 'success' metric for claims of "PhDs are a waste of time" center around money.

Comment: Exactly so. Like you, I did fine. My house is nice and I eat well. No big box of krugerrand, though,

Comment: I always tell my students that they should go into New York law if they want to make tons of money with a quick graduate degree. I'd then also mention that I have Fridays off while they work 90 hours a week.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, you probably work 24/7/52. But the work is indistinguishable from fun. Imagine, getting paid to think.

Comment: @Buffy I don't know, it's nice when you like your work and everything, but that mindset of "if you love your work, why don't you work on weekends and holidays" is what causes burnouts in academia and other fields (computer science, for instance).

Comment: @user4052054 I'm not convinced that passion leads to working weekends (causing burnouts). Regardless of how passionate a researcher is, they know they must rest.

Answer (score 5):

Philip Guo writes a lot of advice, including an e-book about earning a PhD.

http://pgbovine.net/PhD-memoir.htm

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [Teach undergraduates that doing a PhD will require them to embrace failure](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-06905-0). The author is a molecular biologist, not a mathematician.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [this](http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/) short "Illustrated Guide to a Ph.D." by Matt Might? It's a personal favorite of mine. He is a computer scientist but there is not much advice about why it's not for everyone. However, it's worth a read regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the article I was looking for, [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~harchol/gradschooltalk.pdf). Although the author isn't a popular computer scientist, I did find parts of it quite useful.